# Updating react state after data is sent to api

Tags: javascript, reactjs

So it seems I broke the React way of things. I currently have things setup that the main App container (which contains all the router logic) will fetch all data from the API on it's initial state.

I pass down the function:

```
  createPage(page) {
    console.log('submitted')
    instance.post('/admin/createPage',page).then((response) => {
      console.log(response)
    }).catch((error) => {
      console.log(error)
    })
  }
```

The API accepts the data and I see it update the database.

My issue is: after I submit the data, the container component doesn't update it's state which holds all the data.

For example, this is the App container:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
  BrowserRouter as Router,
  Route
} from 'react-router-dom'
import axios from 'axios'

import Header from '../components/Header'

import Dashboard from './Dashboard'
import AddEditPage from './AddEditPage'

const instance = axios.create({baseURL: 'http://localhost:1337'})



class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      "pages": []
    }
    this.createPage = this.createPage.bind(this)
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.getPages()
  }

  getPages() {
    instance.get('/admin/listPages')
      .then(
        (response) => {
          this.setState(
            {
              "pages": response.data
            }
          )
        })
      .catch((error) => {console.log(error)})
  }

  createPage(page) {
    console.log('submitted')
    instance.post('/admin/createPage',page).then((response) => {
      console.log(response)
    }).catch((error) => {
      console.log(error)
    })
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Router>
        <div className="Router">
          <div className="Navbar">
            <Header />
          </div>
          <div className="Wrapper">
            <Route exact path="/" render={ () => (
              <Dashboard pages={this.state.pages} />
            )} />
            <Route path="/admin/new-page" render={ () => (
              <AddEditPage createPage={this.createPage} />
            )} />
            <Route path="/admin/edit-page/:id" render={ () => (
              <AddEditPage />
            )} />
          </div>
        </div>
      </Router>

    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Currently, I get around this issue by setting the window.href after submit. This reloads the whole page (not ideal).

```
  handleSubmit(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    this.props.createPage(this.state)
    //TODO: update main container state of page titles, then redirect
    window.location = "/"

  }
```

Answer (score 2):

`this.getPages` is only being called on `componentDidMount` - so after the component initially mounts, your state is never updated. You need to call `this.getPages` again after creating the new page:

```
createPage(page) {
  console.log('submitted')
  instance.post('/admin/createPage',page).then((response) => {
    console.log(response);

    // after page is created, refetch pages
    // this.getPages calls setState and your component will re-render
    this.getPages();
  }).catch((error) => {
    console.log(error);
  })
}
```

or if you prefer you can chain it in your `handleSubmit`:

```
handleSubmit(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  this.props.createPage(this.state).then(this.getPages);
}
```

Comment: I've tried that originally, but doesn't seem to work. The console.log(response) doesn't seem to be called either. I tried to chain it in the handleSubmit and get this error: TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined

Comment: For some reason, the data is going through the api, but .then is being called.